# Remove whitespace in label (table)

Tags: graphviz

I've tried different things, but can't seem to make the yellow labels any narrower (so they just fit the text).

*Note: I'm not too concerned about the overlap of the labels for now.*

```
digraph G {
  graph [splines=line ranksep=.7 nodesep=1]
  node [shape=rect]
  edge [labelangle=0 labeldistance=3 headlabel=<
    <table bgcolor="yellow" border="1"><tr>
      <td border="0">some label</td>
    </tr></table>>];

  a -> spec
  a -> dot
  spec -> b
  dot -> b
}
```

[image]

Note: After fooling with this a bit more, it looks like adding a font like -  `fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans" fontsize = 10` fixes the spacing issue. Still wondering if there is a more "deterministic" way..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FIXEDSIZE` attribute of a cell. (Docs on [this page](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html), search "fixedsize"). This attribute enforces the height and the size of the cell you specified so it won't adjust to the containing text.

```
digraph G {
  graph [splines=line ranksep=.7 nodesep=1]
  node [shape=rect]
  edge [labelangle=0 labeldistance=3 headlabel=<
    <table bgcolor="yellow" border="1"><tr>
      <td height="20" width="40" fixedsize="true" border="0">some label</td>
    </tr></table>>];

  a -> spec
  a -> dot
  spec -> b
  dot -> b
}
```

Result on my machine:

[image]

You could also use the same attribute `FIXEDSIZE` on the whole table, that would give a slightly different effect:

[image]

PS. Remember, that, as the docs state, for `FIXEDSIZE` attribute to take effect you need to specify *both* `height` and `width` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but computing the size of the cells is *not* what I want to have to do. GV does that pretty nicely for most cases. I think that when the font is unspecified, there might be a bug in the computation.

Comment: @RoyM well actually when I ran your code on my machine I didn't get that big whitespace at the end, the box ended right after the last letter. That's why I thought you want the box to be even smaller than the text. May be some issue with the fonts indeed

Comment: I'm guessing the default font is different, and gv doesn't know which one is being used. Sounds like it's guess on yours is better than on mine.